# Npm run build causes Error:This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

I am following the [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JoQpqYqa7jQ) video to integrate VueJS into Asp.Net Core 2.2 MVC application, I am totally new to VueJS.

The source code is:https://github.com/dotnettec/Integrating-Vue-js-with-ASP.Net-Core-MVC

After adding `package.json` and `webpack.config.js`, when I try to run `npm run build`, it does not generate `bundle` folder in `wwwroot` and it has error:

```
PM> npm run build

> vue-mvc@1.0.0 build C:\Workspace\AspNetCoreWithVueJS\AspNetCoreWithVueJS\AspNetCoreWithVueJS
> cross-env NODE_ENV = production webpack --progress --hide-modules

  npm : 'cross-env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
At line:1 char:1
+ npm run build
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ('cross-env' is ...ternal command,:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

operable program or batch file.

npm


ERR!


code
 ELIFECYCLE

npm

ERR!


errno
 1

npm

ERR!
 vue-mvc@1.0.0 build: `cross-env NODE_ENV = production webpack --progress --hide-modules`

npm

ERR!
 Exit status 1

npm

ERR!



npm

ERR!
 Failed at the vue-mvc@1.0.0 build script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.



npm
 ERR!
 A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm
ERR!
     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-12T06_45_04_074Z-debug.log
```

Could you find how to make it work with above link?

node version: v10.15.3
npm version: 6.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe to give some insight on the Topic.

npm run "build" calls the script via command line defined in the package.json at the scripts object:

`"scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules"
  },`

It looks like that the cross-env command is not recognized as command therefore i suggest you install [Crossenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) from npm, if not already done so
Depending on your OS other steps might be necessary.

```
npm install --save-dev cross-env
```

Answer (score 0):

In my sanario I was not having VUE JS CLi installed on to my server thus

```
// to install vue on ubuntu
npm install -g @vue/cli
// check if it was installed successfully
vue --version
@vue/cli 4.1.2
```

After that you can build VUE app

```
 npm install 
 npm run build
```

Answer (score -1):

Usualy it means that you need run npm install before build your application.

Try this way:

```
 $ npm install 
 $ npm run build
```